# All my IBOutlet are nil in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I've created a `UIViewController` that we can call `MyViewController1`. When I call `MyViewController1`, all my `IBOutlet` are **nil** in `viewDidLoad` (and in the rest of the code too).

When I create this controller by doing
`MyViewController1 *vc = [[MyViewController1  alloc] init]`,

if I replace `MyViewController1` by an other one, for example `MyViewController2`, it works. So I guess the problem is really in `MyViewController1`.

Last thing you might want to know, is that `MyViewController1` is actually a subclass of `MySuperViewController1` that is a `UIViewController`.

Thanks for your help !

---

EDIT

I realized my case was maybe more complicated. Here are my exact files :

// MySuperViewController1

```
MySuperViewController1.h

MySuperViewController1.m

MySuperViewController1.xib
```

// MyViewController1

```
MyViewController1.h

MyViewController1.m
```

So the nib belongs to the superclass, and not the subclass. Can I do that ?

Comment: `MyViewController1 *vc = [[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"younibname"];` Have it a try.

Comment: How about `MyViewController1 *vc = [[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MySuperViewController1"];`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should probably use :

```
MyViewController1 *vc = [[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController1" bundle:nil]
```

calling `init` won't do the match with your xib file and won't alloc your differents `IBOutlet`

EDIT :

There are two possibles solutions :

First is calling init with super nibName :

```
MyViewController1 *vc = [[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MySUperViewController1" bundle:nil]
```

The second is calling the super `initWithNibName:` in child init method :

```
-(id)init {
   if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"MySuperViewController1" bundle:nil]) {
        // Init
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my question : the nib belongs to the superclass, and not the subclass.

Comment: Then you should be able to do `MyViewController1 *vc = [[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MySuperViewController1"]`

Comment: `initWithNibName:` isn't defined.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after after breaking my head i realised naming the xib same as the class name solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me possibly hours of going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether IBoulet is linked properly with xib or not. Also check the files owner of your xib.

If your class name or xib name is changed
Try to allocate you viewcontroller with proper xibName

```
MyViewController1 *vc = [[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my question : the nib belongs to the superclass, and not the subclass.

Comment: Have you ever renamed your class or nib name? also Check your filesowner as I mentioned before..