# IBOutlets from xib are not initialised if I run an app on iOS8 Simulator

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios-simulator, swift2

I have build an app using XCode 7 GM (base SDK - iOS9). It works perfectly if I run it on iOS 9 Simulator but if I try to run it on iOS8 it fails here:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("Home", comment: "Home")
    collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "PTHomeCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PTHomeCollectionViewCell")
}
```

with an error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

because a collectionView is nil:
[image]

Of course I have doubled checked that connection in IB is established:
[image]

Could anyone please tell me why collectionView is nil here?

Comment: unexpectedly found nil kind of error mostly solve if you clean and run the app again.

Comment: Thank you but it not helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    let name = NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil ?? name, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

to the view controller class. But why it works this way? Is there another way to fix this issue?

**Update**:
It is an Swift view controllers feature that is very similar to a bug. Check [Can't Load UIViewController XIB file in Storyboard in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538995/cant-load-uiviewcontroller-xib-file-in-storyboard-in-swift) and [Are view controllers with nib files broken in ios 8 beta 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149604/are-view-controllers-with-nib-files-broken-in-ios-8-beta-5/25152545#25152545)

It is fixed in iOS 9.4 but if you need iOS 8 and earlier support you still need to use workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is highlighted in Matt Neuburg's book *Programming iOS 8*. This happens because iOS 8 expects xib names to be prefixed with module name which is the same as name of project in this case. For example, if you have `MyViewController` in your project `MyProject`, it will expect to find the xib named `MyProject.MyViewController.xib`. To workaround this, override `nibName` in your view controller:

```
override var nibName: String? { 
    return "\(self.dynamicType)"
}
```

Comment: But will it work if I do not want to prefix all my xibs with the module name?

Comment: Yes. Just override `nibName` as I show and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

How are you instantiating your view controller?

Instantiating via `viewController = MyViewController()` will crash in iOS8.x when accessing the `IBOutlets` (though it works ok in iOS9.3, and presumably in iOS9.x)

Instantiating the view controller with `viewController = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)` should work no matter the version of iOS.

See this other posting for reference: [All my IBOutlet are nil in viewDidLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722805/all-my-iboutlet-are-nil-in-viewdidload)